# Problems Installing PIP and Virtualenv when setting up a Python CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: windows, python, pip

Please see the following errors etc.

I get the following error messages when trying to install `pip` in my CMD prompt:

```
C:\cicdbuzz>pip-v
'pip-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

and

```
C:\cicdbuzz>get pip-19.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl 'get' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\cicdbuzz>get-pip.py
'get-pip.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

> Are you using Windows? – Kulfy yesterday

Yes.

```
C:\cicdbuzz>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 6465-B18E

 Directory of C:\cicdbuzz

07/08/2019 20:15 <DIR> .
07/08/2019 20:15 <DIR> ..
06/08/2019 08:18 <DIR> buzz
06/08/2019 07:38 507 OS (C) - Shortcut.lnk
07/08/2019 20:13 1,414,720 pip-19.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
06/08/2019 14:33 <DIR> virtualenv-16.7.2 
             2 File(s) 1,415,227 bytes 
             4 Dir(s) 919,106,113,536 bytes free
```

Also, I can't install this:

```
 Directory of C:\cicdbuzz 

06/08/2019 14:35 <DIR> .
06/08/2019 14:35 <DIR> ..
06/08/2019 08:18 <DIR> buzz
06/08/2019 07:38 507 OS (C) - Shortcut.lnk
06/08/2019 14:33 <DIR> virtualenv-16.7.2 

              1 File(s) 507 bytes 
              4 Dir(s) 919,500,120,064 bytes free 

C:\cicdbuzz>virtualenv venv
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

> [Y]ou need to run python get-pip.py. If that doesn't work, you might need to set environment variables. – Kulfy yesterday

I also get this error:

```
C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 6465-B18E

 Directory of C:\

07/08/2019  20:15    <DIR>          cicdbuzz
16/12/2018  02:34    <DIR>          eSupport
23/07/2019  04:18    <DIR>          Program Files
11/07/2019  03:13    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
16/12/2018  14:20    <DIR>          Users
29/07/2019  19:33    <DIR>          Windows
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  918,969,917,440 bytes free

C:\>cd cicdbuzz

C:\cicdbuzz>python get-pip.py
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Install Python**

First, install [Python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). You will almost certainly want to use the latest version of Python 3.x, as Python 2.x will officially be [EOL by January 2020](https://pythonclock.org/). As of this writing, the current version of Python 3 is [Python 3.7.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-374/).

During the installation, you should do the following:

- Check the options to install `pip` and (optionally) `py launcher`:

*ex. Python Installation Screen 1:*

[image: Python Installation Screenshot 1]

- Assuming you want `.py` (Python script) files to be launched with this version of Python, choose the option to associate `.py` files with Python (requires `py launcher`, above).
- If you want to use `python` from the command line, you will also want to mark the option to add Python to your environment variables.
- For compatibility with cross-platform Python modules (and to avoid other issues), install Python into a directory path *without spaces*. That is, do not use e.g. `Program Files`, `Program Files(x86)` or any other folder that includes spaces (possibly including those under your Windows `User` folder).

*ex. Python Installation Screen 2:*

[image: Python Installation Screenshot 2]

---

**After Installation**

It's important to remember it may be necessary to log off, then log on (or even reboot) after installing Python to ensure that running `python` at the command line works correctly. You can check the location of Python on Windows with `where python` and simply using `python` should give you a command line interpreter (designated with `>>>`).

If `python` doesn't return an error, you should then run e.g. `python -m pip install -U pip` to upgrade `pip` to the latest version.

Note that the proper way to check your version of `pip` is `pip -v` (or rather `python -m pip -v`), not `pip-v`. Python also has `python -v`, if you're curious.

---

*Be aware that for both `pip` and `python`, the `-v` switch is verbose while `-V` isn't.*

---

**get-pip.py and virtualenv**

[get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) shouldn't be necessary if you've followed the steps above, since a version of `pip` should already be installed.

However, if you insist on using it:

- Download the script from the link.
- Make certain `python` is registered at the command line.
- Run `python get-pip.py` in the same directory as the `get-pip.py` script.

> Also, I can't install this: `C:\cicdbuzz>virtualenv venv`

`virtualenv` and `venv` are completely separate Python modules.

[venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) is a native Python module for virtual environments and does not need to be installed with `pip`. You can simply run e.g. `python -m venv new_virtual_env_name` to create a new Python virtual environment called `new_virtual_env_name`.

[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) is a separate Python module, a portion of which has been integrated into Python to create the `venv` module. You can get it from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) or you can use e.g. `python -m pip install virtualenv` (assuming Python and `pip` are installed correctly). Once installed, you can run e.g. `virtualenv new_virtual_env_name` to create a new Python virtual environment called `new_virtual_env_name`

---

**Installing Wheel Files With pip**

If you want to install an existing `.whl` file, use e.g. `python -m pip install wheel_file_name.whl`.

---

**'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

This simply means that `python` isn't in your Windows path variables. On Windows 7 and 10, you should be able to open the `Search` box and type `env` to get a link to `Edit environment variables for your account`. Click on this link to be taken to your Windows path variables.

*Windows 7*

For Windows 7, you should add the folder containing `python.exe` e.g. `C:\path\to\Python37` to your User `PATH` and/or System `Path` variable(s):

- Highlight the given variable, then click the `Edit` button to change its value.
- Make certain to add a `;` to the last existing folder entry before adding `C:\path\to\Python37` (so add e.g. `;C:\path\to\Python37`).
- Hit `OK` to save your changes when finished. You may need to log off and on again (or even reboot) to have `python` available from the command line.

---

*Note that paths in the User `PATH` variable are available only the current User, while paths in the System `Path` variable are available to all users.*

---

*Windows 10*

For Windows 10, you should again add the folder containing `python.exe` e.g. `C:\path\to\Python37` to your System variables. However, the process is slightly different from Windows 7:

- Click `New` to add a new value.
- Add `C:\path\to\Python37` (no `;` needed).
- Hit `OK` to save your changes when finished. You may need to log off and on again (or even reboot) to have `python` available from the command line.

If you need some visual aids (not for Python), see this [How-To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/).

---

**Notes**

*What is `python -m`?*

`python -m` runs a Python library module as a script. What this means practically is that you don't need have anything set up in your path for them and all their effects are "local" to the current version of Python in use (this is particularly desirable with virtual environments).

*Should I register `pip` at the command line?*

You can technically add e.g. `C:\path\to\Python37\Scripts` to your environment variables (using the steps above) to make `pip` available from the command line. Just be aware that if you `pip install some_module` while in a Python virtual environment, the module will likely be installed into e.g. `C:\path\to\Python37`, not `C:\path\to\Python_Virtaul_Env`. This means when you try to import that module, it may not be found. Using `python -m pip` is the correct alternative.