# Python refuses to be recognized in Command Prompt despite multiple attempts to add to PATH

Tags: command-line, python, environment-variables, path, pip

I've downloaded and uninstalled Python so many times trying to get this to work. No matter what happens I always get:

> "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

All I want to do is download new modules with PIP. I’ve tried the suggestions on so many forums.

My environment variables has this  in both User and System variables:

> "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"

Nothing has worked. Computer has been restarted many a time. Python redownloaded many a time. Has never worked.

Even in the autonomous WinPython command lines and IDLE i cannot access python in its command line.

[image: Added picture of my environment variables and my Command Prompt Responses]

Comment: To check the path settings, just type `path` instead of `%path%`.  By the way, is python really there in the folder C:\Users\Owner\...\Python39?  And is the executable named `python3` and `pip3` instead of `python` and `pip`?

Comment: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 is where the installer keeps naturally wanting to place it (despite the fact you cant get into AppData or see that folder without typing this whole big ugly line), in there is all the stuff it normally downloads with. In its Scripts folder is pip, pip3, pip3.8, easy_install, and easy_install-3.8

Comment: python.exe confirmed in folder C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

Comment: Will you want to try to split the line "C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python39" in the "Edit Environment Variable" window into three lines?

Comment: Yeah sadly that didn't help it.

Comment: What does it show up if you type `path` in command prompt?  Not `%path%`

Comment: Shows all the same items as in Environment Variables, separated with semi-colons of course. 
Not sure why this happens to me, on a fairly popular windows computer. I recall similar problems occurring when i tried using extraneous modules with R. Never solved that either.

Comment: 1. Can you run other executable under some other folder (e.g. `robocopy` which is normally under C:\Windows\System32)?
2. If you change directory (`cd`) to the [Python path] and then run `python` does it work?

Comment: python modified my path without me having to do so. it made 2 entries in the path as follows:    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;

Comment: Your system `PATH` is malformed _(only one entry per line via GUI)_, which means the one with three on it is incorrectly separated when viewed as single line of text, and it appears you're also missing several System `PATH` default paths. There's only two things that would cause the issue you're experiencing, either **(1)** The System `PATH` has had a path incorrectly added to it _(which your screenshots show)_; or **(2)** all shell Windows have not been closed to update the shell with the new path value(s).

Answer (score 5):

---

*Disclaimer:*

- *The following suggestions assume that you have installed Python independently on your system and not as a required part of any other program installation.*
- *It assumes you are using "vanilla" Python from `python.org` and not any specialized Python bundle or Python from the Windows Store.*
- *This should not affect Python under WSL as far as I am aware, but that is a supposition.*
- *The suggestions below are generic and it sounds like you may have tried at least some of them, but it is often good to cover all the bases. =)*

---

**General Suggestions**

*Remove Your Existing Environment Variables*

Delete all the environmental variable references to Python in your screenshot. This includes:

- `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts` and any other refrences under your User `PATH` variable

As well as all the references in your System `Path` (as shown in your screenshot):

- `C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python39`
- `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`
- `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`
- `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts`

At best, only two of these would work from the command line directly (one of your Python39 references for `python` and one of your Python38 `Scripts` reference for `pip`) and these aren't even related to the same installation, so they cannot work together for installing modules correctly.

If you want to keep the general `C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python39` entry, that is up to you, but you should remove the `C:\Python39` portion. That said, I believe `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32` are probably redundant in this case, since they should likely be covered by `%SystemRoot%` and `%SystemRoot%\system32` respectively.

---

*Note that you can certainly keep the entries you remove aside (e.g. in Notepad) in case something breaks, but overall, unless another program relies on them, your current layout is not generally the way to handle multiple Python installations on Windows.*

---

*Add One Installation Back*

There two ways to approach this. First, you can simply pick an existing installation you would like to access from the command line and add it back to your environment variables (I would recommend using your System `Path` variable rather than your User `PATH`). So:

```
C:\Python39
C:\Python39\Scripts
```

or:

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

or:

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts
```

Reboot before testing `python` or `pip` from the command line.

If this doesn't work for some reason (or you want to ensure a minimal number of potential issues in the future), I would suggest uninstalling Python (again) from `C:\Python39` and both copies of Python (3.8 and 3.9) from your `Users` folder.

Afterwards, pick one copy of Python to be your primary installation available from the command line and try following these [installation guidelines](https://superuser.com/questions/1469316/problems-installing-pip-and-virtualenv-when-setting-up-a-python-ci-cd-pipeline/1469376#1469376) I wrote for another question. I would be particularly aware of using a custom folder and avoiding `C:\Programs Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)` or anything under `Users` for this installation (these can all potentially cause problems).

**Notes**

- You can add more Python installations to Windows later, if you so choose. That said, while there are ways to use more than one Python version at a time from the command line, only one Python version can technically be available with `python` and `pip` at a time.
- Be aware that Python does not behave like many others Windows programs in that installing a new version will not "upgrade" prior versions. You will simply have two (or more) installations of Python.
- As a general recommendations, Python 3.8 is probably the best Python version to install at this point, since many modules are moving to it. However, for maximum compatibility regarding modules, you may want to consider Python 3.7 (version 3.7.7 currently). I would say Python 3.9 likely doesn't have many modules available for it right now, so unless you have a compelling reason to install it, it probably isn't the best option as of this writing.

---

**Edit**

> Is there a way to just download new packages without pip?

Yes. But as fair warning, while certain modules can be simple to install (assuming you intend to do this), others can be relatively time-consuming (or worse).

The modules that `pip` accesses are all downloaded from the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/). Each "project" (module) hosted there has an individual page that has a `Download files` link for the files hosted on PyPI and (possibly) a `Download` link if an author has provided an alternate source to download the project files from:

*ex. PyPI Project (Module) General Links*

[image: PyPI Project (Module) Links - Screenshot]

*ex. PyPI Project (Module) File Links*

[image: PyPI Project (Module) Links - Screenshot]

As a caveat, while some modules may not have any dependencies, some modules rely on other modules to operate correctly. Unfortunately, it isn't always easy to discover what dependencies a module might have without additional research.

Another pitfall is that some versions of the same modules may only be intended for certain platforms (e.g. Linux, but thankfully these are often marked appropriately).

> All I want is to be able to get the last modules I need for my code so I can send it off[.]

`pip` is probably the last tool you want try using right now, but to be clear, `pip` does not have to be directly available from the command line as just `pip` (via your environment variables) to be used to collect or install packages correctly.

Based on your comments, assuming you chose to install `pip` with Python 3.7 (`pip.exe` is present in `C:\Python37\Scripts`), you should be able to access `pip` for your Python 3.7 installation one of two ways:

```
C:\Python37\python.exe -m pip example-command
```

or directly as:

```
C:\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe example-command
```

With vanilla Python on Windows, environment variables are generally not required to actually run `python.exe` or `pip.exe` successfully for a single Python installation.

*Batch Helper*

Just a thought, but if you don't care to type long paths and can execute `.bat` (batch) files from the command line, you may want to consider creating a "helper" batch file e.g.:

*ex. fake-pip.bat*

```
C:\Python37\python.exe -m pip %*
```

This could allow you easier access to `pip` from any folder with that batch file in it.

---

*Full disclosure: It is still possible to get an error similar to the ones your seeing above if you try to execute ex. `fake-pip` in a directory that *doesn't* contain this batch file.*

*Otherwise, as long as you are careful about keeping this batch file wherever you are working on the command line, you should be able to side-step the "not found" issue you are encountering above.*

---

*fake-pip.bat Examples*

For instance, to install a module into Python 3.7 with `fake-pip.bat`, you should be able to open a command window in the same folder and use:

```
fake-pip install module-name
```

to install that module correctly into Python 3.7.

Note that if you want to simply have a copy of the module and its dependencies on your PC (ex. to put on a disk and give to someone else), you can instead use the `download` option for `pip`:

```
fake-pip download module-name1 module-name2 ...
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Not just the simple solution (fix your path) but also explains why it has to be setup like that.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you so much for all the detail. Sadly this still didn't work. First tried setting path to only a select 2. Rebooted and didn't work. 

Then I deleted all again and deleted all the python files i could and reinstalled. I saved it to C:\Python 3.7 and the setup automatically added it to path. Rebooted. Attempted to open python and run anything related to pip or python in command line...same message as always.

Comment: Is there a way to just download new packages without pip? Or an interactive shell separate from my computer that still lets it affect my computer? All i want is to be able to get the last modules i need for my code so I can send it off to my supervisors, don't care if command line wont accept me for who i am.

Comment: @Chad You're welcome. It's unfortunate you're having this issue. Just to let you know, though, I have updated my answer in response to your comments. But here is the quicky version...

Comment: @Chad *"Is there a way to just download new packages without pip?"* - The short answer is yes. But it may be work, especially if the modules are geared toward taking advantage of `pip` for installation or have a large number of dependencies (which may require some effort to determine what those dependencies are).

Comment: @Chad *"Is there an interactive shell separate from my computer that still lets it affect my computer?"* - I can't think of any offhand, but that doesn't mean they aren't out there (I'm probably missing something obvious...). That said, FYI, you don't need environment variables set to allow e.g. `pip` to work correctly. You just have to type longer paths. You can access `pip` for Python 3.7, for example, with ex. `C:\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe example-command`. However, the way I would recommend using `pip` (because it's good habit anyway) is `C:\Python37\python.exe -m pip example-command`.

Answer (score 0):

Clean (uninstall) your system of all Python installations.  Use RegEdit if necessary.

Then install the Anaconda Navigator distribution.  Make sure you install it (as Windows Administrator) in the directory "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3"  Then use conda to create all your virtual environments. Use 'conda' as your centralized virtual environment manager that comes with Anaconda.  It is cleaner and by default stores all environments into the "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs" directory (if it is configured correctly).

If you still want to use pip / venv, then install conda and pip packages in a conda environment, but follow these instructions:  The best guide to pip and conda together is here: [using conda and pip together](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment)

**BE MINDFUL WHEN USING PIP AND CONDA TOGETHER:**

Be careful about using pip and conda "side-by-side". They each build and manage their own package indexes. Interoperability is still an "experimental feature".   You can try the interoperability feature of conda. [conda and pip interoperability](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html?highlight=pip)

One thing that I usually do is install the conda and pip packages into any new conda environment first (using "conda install -c conda-forge conda pip" at the command line). After that conda then is informed about the pip package installations. I find that pip corrupts my conda environments less frequently when I do this.

See the following document for more information about using pip inside conda environments. [conda and pip interoperability](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html?highlight=pip)

Pip with venv can leave a mess on your system, because it lets you "pip-poop" venv environments all over your file system, like rodent droppings all over an attic.  pip will drop a "venv" virtual environment in whatever directory you happen to be in at the time.  pip does not have a centralized environment manager, which I hate because I forget where I have them and then my system gets cluttered with storage lost to old venv folders that are not centrally managed.  I prefer to let conda automate management by centralizing, tracking, and managing them all in one place.  The conda environment and package manager saves me time, increases productivity and uses my computer more effectively.